# Integration by Substitution choosing u

Tags: calculus, integration

How should I choose $u$ and solve these problems?

1. Integral of the square root of cosecant $x$ to the fifth power times the cotangent of $x$ with respect to $x$ 
   $$\int \sqrt{ \csc^5(x)\cot(x)} dx$$
2. $$ \int4^x \sqrt{1+4^x} dx$$

---

3. $\int x \sqrt{16-3x} dx$

I set $ u$ as $16-3x$, then got $-1/3 \int \sqrt u$.

4. $\int (e^x + 1 )/(e^x)dx$

I tried $u$ = $e^x+1$.

Comment: In #3, I believe you should get $\frac{-1}{9}\int(16-u)\sqrt{u}du$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 4, simply perform division to obtain $\int (1 + e^{-x})$ d$x$.

For 3, Remember that $\int x^n$ d$x=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+C$

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1) Notice $d (\csc x)=-\csc x \cdot \cot x \cdot dx$.

2 $d (4^x)=4^x\ln 4\cdot dx$.